# Continuous scale as legend for color coded map (maps package)

Tags: r, maps, geocoding

I am using the maps package to color code regions of a map:

```
palette = colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(n=9, name='Greens'))(nrow(b))    
palette = palette[rank(b)]
france2<- map(database="france", fill = TRUE, col=palette)
```

I would like to include a legend in the map, that explains what the colors mean. Since the colors are shades of green, I would like to have a continuous scale that goes from light green to dark green. I can't figure out how to do that with this package.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please provide more of your data? In order to assign a fill color, we'll need to know which attribute of the data the scale is based on.

Comment: Also- here's a great resource for mapping with R packages:
http://eriqande.github.io/rep-res-web/lectures/making-maps-with-R.html

Comment: Thank you for that link. Is there any way to do that without ggplot and just with maps? The data that is plotting is just a score on a 100-point scale. Each region (N=95) get a score, most often from 20 to 60.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using `ggplot2` and `dplyr`. I don't know what your actual data looks like that's powering your continuous scale, so I improvised in the code.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

#loading map data
france <- map_data("france")

#creating dummy data for the continuous values that weren't provided in example above
dummy_data <- france %>% distinct(region)

#adding sample values
dummy_data <- dummy_data %>% mutate(Score = sample(x = c(1:100),
                                                   size = nrow(dummy_data),
                                                   replace = TRUE))

#merging sample values with the map's dataframe
france <- france %>% left_join(dummy_data)

#plotting the map
plot <- ggplot() + geom_map(data = france,
                    map = france,
                    aes(x = long, y = lat,map_id = region,
                        group = group,
                        fill = Score),
                    color = "black") +
  scale_fill_gradient(low='lightgreen',high='darkgreen')+
  theme(plot.subtitle = element_text(vjust = 1), 
        plot.caption = element_text(vjust = 1), 
        axis.line = element_line(colour = NA), 
        axis.ticks = element_line(colour = NA), 
        axis.text = element_text(size = 2, colour = NA), 
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA), 
        plot.background = element_rect(colour = NA)) +labs(x = NULL, y = NULL)

print(plot)
```